# | at the beginning of a line - bash

Tags: linux, bash

What does the `|` mean here at the beginning of a line?

```
tr -d '?."!:,();' < manywords \

| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' \

| tr ' ' '\n'
```

The resource I'm using says that this should work but when I run it, I get `syntax error near unexpected token`|'`

Comment: In addition to removing the blank lines, I'd indent the continuation lines (by, say, 4 columns) for greater legibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax error is due the empty lines.

```
tr -d '?."!:,();' < manywords \
| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' \
| tr ' ' '\n'
```

should work. The `\` means "this command continues on the next line", so this is just

```
tr -d '?."!:,();' < manywords | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | tr ' ' '\n'
```

except more readable.

Answer (score 6):

It's a [pipe](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html). The backslash is a line continuation character.

The problem is probably due to the blank lines. Try this instead:

```
tr -d '?."!:,();' < manywords \
| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' \
| tr ' ' '\n'
```

Alternatively you could write it all on one line:

```
tr -d '?."!:,();' < manywords | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

There shouln't be the beginning of a line. The `\` at the end of the previous lines indicates that following newlines should be ignored in processing - from the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Escape-Character):

> A non-quoted backslash () is the escape character.  It preserves the
>   literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception
>   of .  If a \ pair appears, and the backslash is not itself quoted, the \ is treated as a line  continuation 
>   (that  is,  it  is
>          removed from the input stream and effectively ignored)

Your command should be functionally equivalent to

`tr -d '?."!:,();' < manywords | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | tr ' ' '\n'`

but you seem to have added extra newlines.